# Bone Loses Mesh In Pose Mode

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, but I can't seem to get it to work. I want the "hands" to remain aligned with the shirt sleeve, but when I rotate the right arm, the hand mesh leaves the bone constraints and is slightly offset. The left side is working properly, but the right side is not (see attached images). I have everything weighted properly and the meshes are in the correct vertex groups as far as I can tell. File link is below. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Here is the Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i9E91I-sNqQWNsjrVmGcR9IDHfBl2EOj/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right hand is correctly rigged, the problem is that the upper arm bone has influence on the lower arm when it should actually not:

[image]

So set your brush correctly in order to subtract and paint through:

[image]

Paint and it works:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for looking into this!